# When you give a table a name are you temporarily cloning it? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

It's a common question: Write an SQL query to **delete** all the duplicate emails, keeping only one unique email with the smallest id.

Example 1:

Input:
Person table:

```
+----+------------------+
| id | email            |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | john@example.com |
| 2  | bob@example.com  |
| 3  | john@example.com |
+----+------------------+
```

Output:

```
+----+------------------+
| id | email            |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | john@example.com |
| 2  | bob@example.com  |
+----+------------------+
```

I know that to select what I don't want, I have to do something like this:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM Person p1,
    Person p2
WHERE
    p1.Email = p2.Email AND p1.Id > p2.Id
;
```

After that portion I got stuck, so I looked at the answer:

```
DELETE p1
FROM Person p1,
     Person p2
WHERE
     p1.Email = p2.Email AND p1.Id > p2.Id
```

Where I get confused is the second part of the prompt, where you have to **delete** the selection (it doesn't specify this in the prompt, however I am assuming you have to delete from the original table because, practically, someone would go looking for the table "Person" not table "p2" or "p1"). At least I think?

And so... I'm confused how the answer works. I thought that assigning a name to the table (for example "p1" and "p2") creates a temporary copy table, that "p1" and "p2" are physically different tables than "Person". But wouldn't that mean that deleting p1 leaves you with table p2, and that you were able to get the result you needed with table "p2" however the original table "Person" was never modified?

Appreciate any help... the more I think about it the more confused I get, and so I feel like I am missing something very fundamental here. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure how you've arrived at the idea of there being copies of a table (how do you think that would work with a 50m row table?) The `p1, p2` are aliases - alternative *names* used to reference the base object for this specific query. You use `p1` and when the query is compiled it becomes a reference to the actual table. Also, you're using 30+ year-old 1980s join syntax - if this is a learning resource I'd ditch it and find something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `p1` and `p2` are aliases.  They are just shorthand ways of referring to the table.  It's to let you have to type less.

```
SELECT
    customer_orders.partnumber,
    customer_orders.custnumber
FROM
    customer_orders
```

is more typing and reading than

```
SELECT
    co.partnumber,
    co.custnumber
FROM
    co
```

In your case, there are two instances of the `Person` table, so without `p1` and `p2` it would look like this:

```
DELETE Person
FROM Person,
     Person
WHERE
     Person.Email = Person.Email AND Person.Id > Person.Id
```

and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, the key part of the answer is that when the query uses **two intances of the same table** at least one of them must have an alias to distinguishit from the other one.